# How do I remove certain duplicates in a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am writing a query and need it to Remove all duplicates of a.GenUserID but also keep the most recent login date ( that is b.LogDateTime) but this date must be older than 6 months. If there are later dates, they have to be removed.
I hope this makes sense.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.GenUserID, 
    c.DeletionDate, 
    b.LogDateTime,
    (CASE c.Disabled WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' else 'YES - ARCHIVED' end)
FROM RioReport.dbo.GenUser a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.GenUserArchive c on a.GenUserID = c.GenUserID
LEFT JOIN dbo.GenUserAccessHistory b on a.GenUserID = b.ExtraInfo
WHERE(a.Disabled=0 or c.Disabled=0)
    AND c.DeletionDate IS NOT NULL
    AND ((DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > b.LogDateTime or b.LogDateTime IS NULL))
ORDER BY a.GenUserID, b.LogDateTime desc
```

Comment: It really has nothing to do with the tool SSMS.

Comment: You can do INNER JOIN c instead, and remove c.DeletionDate IS NOT NULL. And move the b conditions to the ON clause.

Comment: I need to include  c.deletiondate IS NOT NULL otherwise the results will not be accurate. Please re-look into this for me. And does using inner join remove my duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `row_number()` information to your query, and wrap that query into an outer query that just takes the records with number 1 from that result:

```
select      *
from        (
    select      a.GenUserID, 
                c.DeletionDate, 
                b.LogDateTime,
                case c.Disabled when 0 then 'NO' else 'YES - ARCHIVED' end as diabled,
                row_number() over (partition by a.GenUserID
                                   order by     b.LogDateTime desc) as rn
    from        RioReport.dbo.GenUser a 
    inner join  dbo.GenUserArchive c
            on  a.GenUserID = c.GenUserID
    left join   dbo.GenUserAccessHistory b
            on  a.GenUserID = b.ExtraInfo
    where       (a.Disabled=0 or c.Disabled=0)
    and         c.DeletionDate is not null
    and         (DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > b.LogDateTime or b.LogDateTime is null)
    )
where       rn = 1            
order by    a.GenUserID
```

Note that you can turn the first `left join` into an `inner join` without any change to the result set, since you have a non-null check on one of its fields. `inner join` is then preferred, and might give a performance improvement.

If `GenUserAccessHistory.LogDateTime` is always non-null, then you can avoid the test `or b.LogDateTime is null` by moving the `DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > b.LogDateTime` condition to the appropriate join `on` clause.

The generated row number will be given in order of descending `LogDateTime` values, and restart from 1 for every different user.

#### Alternative without window functions

`row_number()` and other window functions are supported since SQL Server 2008. In comments you write you cannot use it. If that is the case, here is an alternative using a common table expression (supported since SQL Server 2005):

```
;with cte as (
    select      a.GenUserID, 
                c.DeletionDate, 
                b.LogDateTime,
                case c.Disabled when 0 then 'NO' else 'YES - ARCHIVED' end as disabled,
    from        RioReport.dbo.GenUser a 
    inner join  dbo.GenUserArchive c
            on  a.GenUserID = c.GenUserID
    left join   dbo.GenUserAccessHistory b
            on  a.GenUserID = b.ExtraInfo
    where       (a.Disabled=0 or c.Disabled=0)
    and         c.DeletionDate is not null
    and         (DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > b.LogDateTime or b.LogDateTime is null)
    )    
select      *
from        cte main
where       LogDateTime is null
        or  not exists (select   1
                        from     cte sub
                        where    sub.GenUserID = main.GenUserID
                        and      sub.LogDateTime > main.LogDateTime)
order by    GenUserID
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. My network won't let me use the ROW_NUMBER() function so I'll just have to find another way.

Comment: Your network? Which version of SQL Server do you run on?

Comment: While waiting for your reply, I have added an alternative to my answer which should run on SQL Server 2005 or later versions.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "a.GenUserID" could not be bound.

Comment: We are running 2008 R2 but to be honest, in my work a lot of functions are restricted so it's really difficult to get the code right as a lot of expressions are not accepted.

Comment: Indeed, there was an error in the  `order by` of the second SQL. It should be `cte.GenUserID`. Let me know how that works.

Comment: This all works now but actually has not removed any of the ClientID duplicates which is why I needed to change the code in the first place. Any thoughts?

Comment: Indeed. I have updated the second query. Could you have a go at it?

Comment: Ive updated the query but it's still not removing the duplicates!!

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I made another mistake. last condition in the inner query should read: `sub.LogDateTime > main.LogDateTime` (with `sub.` at the left side, not `main.`).

Answer (score 2):

Use cte and window function

```
  ;with ctr as (
    select a.GenUserID, a.DeletionDate, a.LogDateTime 
    row_number()over(partition by a.GenUserID order by b.LogDateTime desc) rnk

    from RioReport.dbo.GenUser a )
    select a.GenUserID, a.DeletionDate, a.LogDateTime,
        CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(mm,LogDateTime,getdate())<6 THEN 'NO' else 'YES - ARCHIVED' end)
     from ctr a where a.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below query.

```
;WITH CTE_Group
AS(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.GenUserID ORDER BY b.LogDateTime DESC) as RNO, 
    a.GenUserID, 
    c.DeletionDate, 
    b.LogDateTime,
    (CASE c.Disabled WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' else 'YES - ARCHIVED' end) IsArchived
FROM RioReport.dbo.GenUser a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.GenUserArchive c on a.GenUserID = c.GenUserID
LEFT JOIN dbo.GenUserAccessHistory b on a.GenUserID = b.ExtraInfo
WHERE(a.Disabled=0 or c.Disabled=0)
    AND c.DeletionDate IS NOT NULL
    AND ((DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > b.LogDateTime or b.LogDateTime IS NULL)))
    SELECT  GenUserID, 
            DeletionDate, 
            LogDateTime,
            IsArchived
    FROM WITH_CTE_Group
    WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was really helpful.